# how to get date with JSON.stringify(data) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date, datetime

In my angular js application i got success response from web service ,and i am trying to displaying the response data in console

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

But the problem is in my success response data has a date element .i have printed the before and after the `JSON.stringify(data)` the outputs are :
**before** :Tue Aug 14 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
**after JSON.stringify(data)** :"2012-08-13T18:30:00.000Z"

in after it shows 13 Aug date instead of 14 Aug date .

please tell me how can i solve this issue,i want to get 14 aug after `JSON.stringify(data)` .

Comment: Seems like both your dates are in different format and different timezones. The first one in GMT+5:30 while the second one is GMT+0. ALso add more code definitely dates are not being printed by your console.log statements

Comment: What's wrong? Both represent the exactly same datetime.

Comment: @Bergi could you please tell me how to get the same format as before json.stingify(data).

Comment: Before stringifying there is no *format*, there is just time. You can either use `.toString` on it to get a representation of it in the local timezone, or you use `.toUTCString()` to get the same representation as `JSON.stringify` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` uses the `toJSON` method - if defined - to serialize objects. `Date` objects have that method defined in their `prototype` indeed, and it's pretty much equivalent to `Date.prototype.toISOString`.

So a solution would be redefining `Date.prototype.toJSON`: I don't really recommend it, as the ISO format is pretty much conventional to transport dates as strings, but it can be done.

This example makes use of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return moment(this).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
};
```

In the end, ask yourself: why should you use `JSON.stringify` to display a date on the console? `Date` has plenty of methods to display dates (`toString`, `toUTCString`, `toLocaleString`, `toISOString`, ... not all of them supported by every browser, to be fair), and if they don't satisfy your needs there are quite some date libraries (like moment.js mentioned above) that can help you.

Comment: In fact, one may have a date property of a larger JSON object that gets stringified. So, the `JSON.stringify` method will eventually end up calling the ToJSON method of each object member. Anyway, the default behaviour should be fine if you pass the stringified json to, let's say, a RESTful API (meaning the latter should be able to handle ISO dates). For debug printing, I don't think the format would (neither should ) matter at all.